# I have question on basic c program for calculating Simple interest; program 1 works but program 2 doesn't work. why? Please help, I am new to coding

Tags: c, computation

Program 1

```
int main() {
    int p, t;
    float r;
    printf("please enter the principle amount\n");
    scanf("%d", & p);
    printf("please enter the time period of repayment\n");
    scanf("%d", & t);
    printf("please enter the rate of interest for lending\n");
    scanf("%f", & r);
    printf("The simple interest is %f", prt / 100);
    return 0;
}
```

Program 2

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    int p, t;
    float r, interest;
    interest = prt / 100;
    printf("please enter the principle amount\n");
    scanf("%d", & p);
    printf("please enter the time period of repayment\n");
    scanf("%d", & t);
    printf("please enter the rate of interest for lending\n");
    scanf("%f", & r);
    printf("The simple interest is %f", interest);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please format the code.

Comment: What is prt? Such an identifier is not declared in the both programs.

Comment: well, program 2 doesn't compile because `prt` isn't defined. Are you trying to multiply `p`, `r`, and `t` together as if using algebraic notation? Even if that worked in C (it doesn't), those values are uninitialized at the `interest = prt / 100;` line, so that invokes undefined behavior. Instructions are executed top to bottom, you'll need to do the multiplication after the values are input.

Comment: program 1 doesn't compile either for the same reason. Share the code you're actually running with.

Comment: Thanks for your quick responses.. somehow text box where I copied the code ignored the * in (p*r*t)...    Also just now I have realized that I have given the formula Interest = p*r*t/100 at very early stage, even before assigning any value so the reason it is returning garbage value. Thanks so much for the help

Answer (score 0):

Let's break down the task of program 2.

You're trying to find out the value of "**interest**" where **interest = ( p * r * t ) / 100**.

First, you need the value of 3 variables which are 'p', 'r', 't'.

You're taking those values from user (using scanf).

You'll be able to get the value of "interest" after taking all those inputs.

So you'll have to assign values in the variable "interest" according to the equations right after you're done with taking those inputs.

That means at the end of the program.

Another thing, when you're writing an equation, you'll have to write down corresponding operators too.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    int p, t;
    float r, interest;

    printf("please enter the principle amount\n");
    scanf("%d", & p);
    printf("please enter the time period of repayment\n");
    scanf("%d", & t);
    printf("please enter the rate of interest for lending\n");
    scanf("%f", & r);

    interest = (p * r *t) / 100.0;
    printf("The simple interest is %f", interest);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the clarification and answer